# What is the difference between Pandas Series.apply() and Series.map()?

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

[Series.map()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html):

> Map values of Series using input correspondence (which can be a dict, Series, or function)

[Series.apply()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html)

> Invoke function on values of Series. Can be ufunc (a NumPy function that applies to the entire Series) or a Python function that only works on single values

`apply()` seems like it does mostly everything `map()` does, vectorizing scalar functions while applying vectorized operations as they are. Meanwhile `map()` allows for some amount of control over null value handling. Apart from historical analogy to Python's `apply()` and `map()` functions, is there a reason to prefer one over the other in general use? Why wouldn't these functions just be combined?

Comment: afaik Series.map(func) cannot pass additional arguments to func. When you use Series.apply(func), you can do sr.apply(func, convert_dtype=True, arg2='foo', arg3=True), and whatever keyword arguments that Series.apply() doesn't recognize will be passed to func, in this case arg2='foo' and arg3=True.

Comment: @xg.plt.py the context of that other question is dataframes rather than series objects (and so the similarity is more profound in this case)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference is subtle:

`pandas.Series.map` will substitute the values of the Series by what you pass into `map`.

`pandas.Series.apply` will apply a **function** (potentially with arguments) to the values of the Series.

The difference is what you can pass to the methods

- both `map` and `apply` can receive a function :

```py
s = pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 4])

def square(x):
     return x**2

s.map(square) 

0    1
1    2
2    3
3    4
dtype: int64

s.apply(square) 

0    1
1    2
2    3
3    4
dtype: int64
```

- However, the function you pass into `map` cannot have more than one parameter (it will output a `ValueError`) :

```py
def power(x, p):
    return x**p

s.apply(power, p=3)

0     1
1     8
2    27
3    64
dtype: int64


s.map(power,3)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError
```

- `map` can receive a dictionary (or even a `pd.Series` in which case it will use the index as key ) while `apply` cannot (it will output a `TypeError`)

```py
dic = {1: 5, 2: 4}

s.map(dic)

0    5.0
1    4.0
2    NaN
3    NaN
dtype: float64

s.apply(dic)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError  


s.map(s)

0    2.0
1    3.0
2    4.0
3    NaN
dtype: float64


s.apply(s)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError
```